# Why is delete being called after updating entity in typeorm?

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

When a user creates an organization, I go through and update the active organization once it is created. I take the authenticated user object retrieved from the JWT strategy with the created organization to pass those into the `updateActiveOrganization` method. Doing this creates the following SQL code. I am able to get around this by using the queryBuilder or just getting a new instance of the user, but I would like to avoid another DB query for this to happen. Is there anyway I can use the already created instances to make this happen? I don't have any constraints created that I can see unless the ORM is creating them that I don't see. Thanks.

```
query: INSERT INTO `organization`(`id`, `name`, `location`, `avatar`, `slug`, `createdAt`, `ownerId`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, ?, DEFAULT, ?) -- PARAMETERS: ["test",1]
query: SELECT `Organization`.`id` AS `Organization_id`, `Organization`.`createdAt` AS `Organization_createdAt` FROM `organization` `Organization` WHERE `Organization`.`id` = ? -- PARAMETERS: [22]
query: INSERT INTO `organization_members`(`organizationId`, `userId`) VALUES (?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: [22,1]
query: COMMIT
query: SELECT `User`.`id` AS `User_id`, `User`.`firstname` AS `User_firstname`, `User`.`surname` AS `User_surname`, `User`.`email` AS `User_email`, `User`.`createdAt` AS `User_createdAt`, `User`.`activeOrganizationId` AS `User_activeOrganizationId` FROM `user` `User` WHERE `User`.`id` IN (?) -- PARAMETERS: [1]
query: SELECT `User_organizations_rid`.`organizationId` AS `organizationId`, `User_organizations_rid`.`userId` AS `userId` FROM `organization` `organization` INNER JOIN `organization_members` `User_organizations_rid` ON (`User_organizations_rid`.`userId` = ? AND `User_organizations_rid`.`organizationId` = `organization`.`id`) ORDER BY `User_organizations_rid`.`organizationId` ASC, `User_organizations_rid`.`userId` ASC -- PARAMETERS: [1]
query: START TRANSACTION
query: UPDATE `user` SET `activeOrganizationId` = ? WHERE `id` IN (?) -- PARAMETERS: [22,1]
query: DELETE FROM `organization_members` WHERE `organizationId` = ? AND `userId` = ? -- PARAMETERS: [22,1]
query: COMMIT
```

This is the part I cannot figure out how to stop using the current code setup.

```
query: START TRANSACTION
query: UPDATE `user` SET `activeOrganizationId` = ? WHERE `id` IN (?) -- PARAMETERS: [22,1]
query: DELETE FROM `organization_members` WHERE `organizationId` = ? AND `userId` = ? -- PARAMETERS: [22,1]
query: COMMIT
```

User Entity

```
export class User extends BaseEntity {    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    firstname: string;

    @Column()
    surname: string;

    @Column({
        unique: true
    })
    email: string;
    @Column({ select: false })
    password: string;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date;

    /** RELATIONS */
    @OneToOne(type => Organization)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'activeOrganizationId' })
    activeOrganization: Organization;

    @ManyToMany(type => Organization, organization => organization.members)
    organizations: Organization[];
}
```

Organization Entity

```
@Entity()
export class Organization extends BaseEntity {
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({
        length: 80,
        unique: true,
    })
    name: string;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date; 

    
    @ManyToOne(type => User)
    @JoinColumn()
    owner: User;

    @ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.organizations) 
    @JoinTable({ name: 'organization_members' })
    members: User[];
}
```

Update Code

```
    async updateActiveOrganization(updateData: IUpdateActiveOrganization): Promise<void> {
        const { user, organization } = updateData;
        user.activeOrganization = organization;
        await user.save();
    }
```

Comment: I guess it's because you have two different relations defined on the same two tables.
You can't have both one to one and many to many on the same two tables. Oh and you also have many to One. 3 different relations.

Comment: @noamsteiner I just got to testing multiple users with the API last night and found I meant to put the many to one relation on the active organization. I didn't even think to go back and check to see if that was causing the issue there. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i found an acceptable work around for now. If there are better ways, please let me know.

```
await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder()
    .update()
    .set({
        activeOrganization: organization,
    })
    .where('user = :user', user);
```